# Vue instance status and route redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Using [vue.js](https://vuejs.org) and [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org) I would like to have a global status property of the application (something shared between components) and prevent routes depending on the value of this property.

For example if the status is not initialized, I want to redirect all routes to the root "/". 
I've tried the following:

```
Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    routes: routes
})

// global status property
Vue.prototype.$isInitialized = false

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!this.$isInitialized) { // <--- does not work, can't access Vue instance from here
        next("/")
    }
    else {
        next()
    }
})
```

This code does not work because I can't access the Vue instance from the global router hooks. What is the proper way to achieve this behaviour in Vue?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is Vue instance attached in `this.a.app` or `this.app` which the `this` the router instance, not Vue itself.

The `router.beforeEach` is the global navigation guard, and in general, it's better to use `this` to refer to single component, using `this` for global Vue instance will lead to confusing in future.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, from what I can see the router.app or router.apps[0] refers to the global instance Vue, not the specific instance of my application so any change on the global property $isInitialized will not be visible from there

Comment: Since you're adding directly to the `Vue.prototype`, can't you say `if (! Vue.prototype.$isInitialized) { ...`? Not sure if that would work or how far it strays from best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Solved for now attaching the global property to the router instance instead of the Vue instance:

```
Vue.use(Router)

// global status property
Router.prototype.$isAppInitialized = false

const router = new Router({
    routes: routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.path !== "/" && !router.$isAppInitialized) { 
        next("/")
    }
    else {
        next()
    }
})
```

This works because it is possible to access the router instance in the components and update the global property, but feels like an hack to me. Please let me know if there better ways to do this.

Comment: Usually I prefer to set an global Vuex, it can do the same, but Vuex give you more power, functionalities (like getters to compute the complex change) Just my opinion.